# Doctrine OpenApi Swagger issue - The annotation "@OpenApi\Annotations\Schema" in class ... was never imported

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, swagger-php

I'm running into an issue with the Doctrine annotations used with the zircote/swagger-php library. We're doing some dependency upgrades and the Doctrine proxy generation is failing with the error:

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException 

  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@OpenApi\Annotations\Schema" in class ... was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

  at vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:39
     35▕      * @return AnnotationException
     36▕      */
     37▕     public static function semanticalError($message)
     38▕     {
  ➜  39▕         return new self('[Semantical Error] ' . $message);
     40▕     }
     41▕ 
     42▕     /**
     43▕      * Creates a new AnnotationException describing an error which occurred during

      +23 vendor frames 
  24  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I'm including the OA library via `use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;`

The code blocks where it is failing have not changed. Any idea why this might be throwing this error for all of these classes? I'm guessing it must be some kind of dependency mixup or something.